# Two link random php

Tags: php

I have n number of links, each with its own keyword. I would like to show two links at a time, randomly in php. Any suggestion?

Here is input example :

```
$text[1] = "<a href=https://www.website.ext/post-1/>words 1</a>";

$text[2] = "<a href=https://www.website.ext/post-2/>words 2</a>";

$text[3] = "<a href=https://www.website.ext/post-3/>words 3</a>";

$text[4] = "<a href=https://www.website.ext/post-4/>words 4</a>";

$text[5] = "<a href=https://www.website.ext/post-5/>words 5</a>"

....
```

output example :

```
words 1

words 3

or

words 5

words 2

or

words 4

words 1
```

Comment: have you tried with the `mt_rand()` function?

Comment: **Pro tip:** Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on attempting to solve your own problem prior to a question being posted. 
We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Comment: Or just Google it and one of the top results is: https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Comment: At this time I use this code:


// Add more $text[X] = "Random text"; if you want more than six ;)
$text[1] = "<a href=url>1</a>";
$text[2] = "<a href=url>2</a>";
$text[3] = "<a href=url>3</a>";
$text[4] = "<a href=url>4</a>";
$text[5] = "<a href=url>5</a>";


// Picking a random number
$num = rand(1, count($text));
floor($num);

// Showing the text associated with the random number
echo $text[$num ];

It works well but only shows one link at a time. 

How can I show 2 or more links? I'm not familiar with php

Comment: Do the same thing twice. Or if I was doing it: `shuffle($array);` then `echo implode("<br>", array_slice($array, 0,2));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach this as

```
 $arr = [
  '<a href=https://www.website.ext/post-1/>words 1</a>',
  '<a href=https://www.website.ext/post-2/>words 2</a>',
  '<a href=https://www.website.ext/post-3/>words 3</a>',
  '<a href=https://www.website.ext/post-4/>words 4</a>',
  '<a href=https://www.website.ext/post-5/>words 5</a>'
];
$res = array_rand($arr,2);
echo $arr[$res[0]];
echo '<br/>';
echo $arr[$res[1]];
```

Comment: answer updated, you can use <br/> or any other separater you want

Comment: Many thanks Rakesh Jakhar, you have been of great help to me. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of code that you can follow to achive your task.
You can use the [mt_rand()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) function to select a random index from the array and then echo it, or the [array_rand()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) function that will extract randomly from the array the given number of elements.

```
<?php
#example 1
$text = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

$keys = array_rand($text, 2);

echo $text[$keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $text[$keys[1]] . "\n";

#example 2

$text = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

echo $text[mt_rand(0,4)] . "\n";
echo $text[mt_rand(0,4)] . "\n";

?>
```